# Why does TCP networking (receiving data) in .NET/C# throw an exception when trying to receive?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have been working with sockets to send data in C# and it's working, with this code:

```
string ipAddress = "x.y.z.a";   // replace with a real IP address
int port = 2809;
string data = "foo";

Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

if (!clientSocket.Connected)
    clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);

clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
clientSocket.Disconnect(true);
clientSocket.Close();
clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

Now I want it to receive data, but I can't get it to work because when I add `socket.Receive()` the program crashes. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: "When I add `socket.Receive`" -- that would be an adequate description if we were making cocktails. However, it's not adequate as the description of a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon is suggesting, it's not quite clear *where* you are trying to add the receive code. I mean, the last line(s) of your example is a bit confusing in that you first close the socket, then create a new one. Why? Similar with the "if (!clientSocket.Connected)" stuff first; if you create a fresh socket, there should be no need whatsoever to check if it is connected. Of course it's not, you just created it! :-)

Anyway, if I just add some code after yours like this:

```
byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
clientSocket.Receive(receiveBuffer);
```

...and change the `ipAddress` and `port` accordingly, to a known good service on my network, I get a `SocketException` with a message saying *"A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"*.

However, if I insert the receiving code so that the send/receive looks like this:

```
int bytesSent = clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

var receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
var sb = new StringBuilder();
int receivedBytes;
while ((receivedBytes = clientSocket.Receive(receiveBuffer)) != 0)
{
    // NOTE: this presumes that the data coming from the remote end is ASCII-
    // encoded, which might not be the case at all. Don't copy this approach
    // blindly without thinking
    string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, receivedBytes);
    sb.Append(s);
}

var response = sb.ToString(); // at this point you should have all the data that
                              // has been received from the remote, so far.

clientSocket.Disconnect(true);
clientSocket.Close();
```

This code works for me; it gives me the response to my request (around 3 KiB in my case).

On a more philosophical/architectural level, I definitely suggest though, that if you don't really *need* to go down to the socket level (for whatever reason) to prefer using one of the more high-level classes of the framework. [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) is one alternative (works with all >1.1 versions of the framework, e.g. virtually all versions in active use today). [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) is another one, if you are on .NET 4.5 (there is a [back-port available](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) also from [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org).

Of course, this blindly presumes that what you want to do is to perform HTTP requests (which, it turns out, is quite common these days). There are also other alternatives like [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) for FTP, etc etc.

In my experience (working as a programmer for a bit more than 10 years), it's actually very uncommon to have to go down as deep as to the socket level, *especially* recently given how much of the common scenarios are supported in the BCL (base class library, e.g. the .NET standard assemblies provided by Microsoft) or NuGet. Such existing clients have the huge, huge advantage of other people having spent a considerable amount of time on it, nailing out the bugs, quirks and so forth, so you can start focusing on the problem you really want to solve, rather than fixing bugs which have actually been fixed many, many times before...

(Of course, there are exceptions, but I feel this is definitely the general rule of thumb.)

Comment: Your example has the problem that `Receive` may return less data than requested. It's usually necessary to call `Receive` in a loop until it returns `0` (indicating the end of the stream).

Comment: Good point. It wasn't intended as the "final solution" to anything; it worked for me in this trivial example, and would perhaps have been enough to get the poster going in some reasonably correct direction. Nonetheless, I've now fixed it so that it reads the full response. Thanks for suggesting.